# How to save data in same row?

Tags: php, arrays, function

Hi how I can save data in same row in database I'm saving to database using this code but it's saving in different two rows please help me thanks. here is screenshot of database.
[image: Screenshot]

```
<?php

    $users = array("username"=>"Kaleem", "address"=>"abc");

class dbase{

    public function dbinsert($table,$users)
    {
        foreach ($users as $key => $value) 
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (`$key`) VALUES ('$value')";
            $success = $this->conn->query($sql);
            if($success)
            {
                echo "Data inserted";
            }
        }
    }


        public function __construct ()
        {

            $this->conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','dbase');

            if($this->conn)
            {
                echo "Connected<br>";
            }
        }


}

$obj = new dbase;
$obj->dbinsert('users',$users);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

    $users[] = array("username"=>"Kaleem", "address"=>"abc");

class dbase{

    public function dbinsert($table,$users)
    {
        foreach ($users as $key => $value) 
        {
            $username = $value['username'];
            $address = $value['address'];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (`username`,`address`) VALUES ('".$username."','".$address."')";
            $success = $this->conn->query($sql);
            if($success)
            {
                echo "Data inserted";
            }
        }
    }

        public function __construct ()
        {

            $this->conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','dbase');

            if($this->conn)
            {
                echo "Connected<br>";
            }
        }


}

$obj = new dbase;
$obj->dbinsert('users',$users);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I recommend array to be:

```
$users = array(array("username"=>"Kaleem", "address"=>"abc"));
```

This way, each user will be an array inside that big $users array. If you do that, your php code should be:

```
<?php

$users = array("username"=>"Kaleem", "address"=>"abc");

class dbase{

public function dbinsert($table,$users)
{
    foreach ($users as $user) //better have descriptive names in variables, and we do not need to know the key! 
    {
        $username = $user['username']; 
        $user_address = $user['addess'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (`username`, 'addess') VALUES ('$username','$user_address')"; //lets insert both of them in the same row
        $success = $this->conn->query($sql);
        if($success)
        {
            echo "Data inserted";
        }
    }
}


    public function __construct ()
    {

        $this->conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','dbase');

        if($this->conn)
        {
            echo "Connected<br>";
        }
    }


}
$obj = new dbase;
$obj->dbinsert('users',$users);
```

I hope this explanation is enough, you where iterating over username and address as elements, and inserting them each in a different row instead of doing it in a single row.